# Getting numbers from parse.com object in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have an object/list coming from parse.com(using parse sdk) and receive both strings and numbers. While I am able to fetch strings I don't know how to fetch numbers.

This works fine for string as driver:

```
ParseObject u = (ParseObject)scoreList.get(i);
    String truckName;
 truckName = u.getString("driver").toString();
```

How do I get the number assuming my "xcor" (assume another property such as "driver") is a number not string.

Comment: what data type you have specified in parse database for `driver` and `xcor`

Comment: For driver it is string which I can get from above. The xcor is a number like 23.647753.

Comment: you can do like this `String.valueOf(user.get("columnName"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your question perfectly, but isn't this:

```
double xcor = u.getDouble("xcor");
```

just what you need?

*(alternatively if you store integer instead of a double you can use `int otherVariable = u.getInt("otherVariable");`)*

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work. I think getString is a custom method by parse.com. I have to check and let you know.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, because I use it all the time. Damn, I even wrote [an annotation processor](https://github.com/blipinsk/Android-ParseModel) that makes it much easier to create a Parse.com data model and it's using it as well.

Comment: And [`getDouble`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getDouble(java.lang.String)) is (just as [`getString`](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html#getString(java.lang.String))) a standard `ParseObject's`method from the Parse SDK  ("custom method by parse.com") .

Comment: No worries, Ill check over weekend. Thanks